# Why can't certain users copy and paste between local session and Remote Desktop session?

Tags: rdp, clipboard, clipboard-sharing

I have two users experiencing this problem and I've gone through all the possible fixes I can find with no luck. I'm hoping someone has another idea. Here is the info to clarify the problem.

2 users recently got new laptops (Windows 7) and both noticed the problem only after getting the new laptops.

When they remote desktop to any servers on our network, the copy/paste clipboard functionality won't work between the local and remote session, but only sporadically. Sometimes it will actually work.

When using a remote desktop connection to something outside our network, the clipboard functionality works fine.

Here's what I've tried:

- restarting rdpclip on the remote session
- checking that the clipboard is selected and local drives are selected in the RDP options under local resources
- server side is fine as other users have no problem with clipboard functionality on these same servers
- New laptops for these users are in the same AD organizational unit as the rest of our office

Any Ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You might encourage more answers if you accepted some of the better answers on your other questions.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I was supposed to do that

Comment: @Mike: is the for only clipboard, or also files?  If the user right-clicks and attempts to paste some data, is the Paste menu option dimmed, or does it just not do anything when they select Paste?

Comment: Good point Greg, it doesn't work for files and for text. I will check with the users about the paste option being greyed out.

Comment: One user now reports that they can copy text, but not files